# How to get an account address from Metamask?

Tags: ethereum, solidity, web3js

`accounts[0]` returns `undefined` in this code.

```
const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts()
console.log(accounts[0])
```

I uninstalled Metamask and reset the account, but that didn't work.

web3 version is web3@1.0.0-beta.37.

Could you give me any advise, why I cannot get an account address from Metamask?

Comment: `web3.eth.accounts[0]` works fine for me, make sure that you log in into your metamask account

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There was a Metamask connection error.
I connected to web3 by coding this.

```
Web3(window.web3.currentProvider)
```

However, this code is better for modern wallet.

```
web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum)
    window.ethereum.enable().catch(error => {
        // User denied account access
        console.log(error)
    })
```